# SVG Clip Path working locally but not online

Tags: html, svg

The following svg clip-path works fine locally but not online:

```
<svg xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 0 0 200 166.414" viewBox="0 0 200 166.414" y="0px" x="0px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

    <clipPath id="mask1">
        <rect height="116.673" width="116.673" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#fff" fill="none" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 87.559 -44.972)" y="24.871" x="39.729"/>
    </clipPath>

    <line y2="82.438" x2="200" y1="82.438" x1="180" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#fff" fill="none"/>
    <line y2="82.438" x2="17" y1="82.438" x1="0" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#fff" fill="none"/>
    <rect height="116.673" width="116.673" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#fff" fill="none" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 87.559 -44.972)" y="24.871" x="39.729"/>
    <rect height="107.393" width="107.393" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#fff" fill="none" opacity="0.2" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 87.5595 -44.9719)" y="29.511" x="44.369"/>
    <image xlink:href="/content/events/eventImage_5.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#mask1)"/>
</svg>
```

Maybe it is something else I'm missing .. I have been trying all sorts of ways but still with no luck. The live example can be seen here: http://akrotirilounge.gr/index

You can see the example at the very top where the event image should be clipped as a diamond shape instead it is not clipped at all. This renders perfectly locally in all compatible browsers.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `<base>` tag

```
<base href="http://akrotirilounge.gr/" />
```

So when you write `clip-path="url(#mask1)"`

you're actually writing `clip-path="url(http://akrotirilounge.gr/#mask1)`

So you could do one of:

- fix the clip-path to contain an absolute URL
- Add /image to the clip-path
- remove the `<base>` element

Comment: Excellent!! That makes absolute sense and it works as expected. Thank you Robert.

Comment: @Robert Longson could you say more about adding "/image to the clip-path" ?